# Windows Phone 8 SDK installation

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-embedded-8

I have installed Windows Phone 8 SDK and Windows 8 Embedded Handheld on Windows 8 64Bit Machine, which has Visual Studio 2013 Express installed, I am trying to run Windows 8 Embedded 8 Handheld Sample application `Barcode Scanner` provided from Microsoft web site.

But problem is:

- I am not able to see Windows Phone 8 SDK or Windows Embedded 8
  Handheld SDK in about screen of Visual Studio 2013 as given in
  [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2YdZhP8N7Y) video.
- When i open Blend tool which comes with the sdk, and after creating sample application and try to trn it emulator starts loading
  and fails with `error code 32775`.
- Also i am not able to see option to create Windows Store App from `New Project` options.
- Also I am not able to open any project with the extension `.csproj`

So How can i fix these issue?
How to properly install both this SDKs so that i can use them from Visual Studio 2013 Express. 
I have all the hardware requirements as given on the Microsoft website, for running the emulator. (Hyper-V and SLAT).

Answer (score 1):

*Visual Studio 2013 **Express** for Windows* targets Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 only. In the video Andy is using *Visual Studio 2013 **Ultimate***. VS2013 Express for Windows runs only on Windows 8.1, so I suspect you have a different version of VS2013 Express which doesn't support Windows Store apps.

To target Windows Phone 8 you'll need [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff630878(v=vs.105).aspx) or a non express version of Visual Studio 2013.

You should have Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8 installed with the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have now installed Windows Phone 8 SDK with Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition + Update 4, but still I don't see options to create Windows Store App, also I don't see installed SDK in About screen of the Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Are you trying to create a Windows Phone app or a Windows Store app? They use different versions of Visual Studio 2012 express: Windows Store apps use Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows. Windows Phone apps use Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone. The two platforms (Windows Store and Windows Phone) don't merge until Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows, which supports Universal apps.

Comment: I want to run the sample application Barcode Scanner for Windows 8 Embedded Handheld, which is what Store or Phone App? Also i have tried same setup with Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition, but same problem. Is it diff. version of 2013 also, totally confused!!

Comment: Windows 8 Embedded Handheld builds on top of Windows Phone 8. I think the confusion is that in VS2013 WP8 templates are listed under Windows Store. VS2012 Express for Windows Phone only does Windows Phone so the template hierarchy isn't as deep.

Comment: I got to know that I will need "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8" for this, Also one more thing what is the diff. between "VS2012 Express For Windows-8" and "VS2012 Express For Windows Phone 8". First one is for Windows-8 apps and 2nd one for Windows-8 Phone app, is it that?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8 is for writing Windows Store 8.0 apps. Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8 is for writing Windows Phone 8.0 apps. Windows Embedded 8 Handheld is based on Windows Phone 8.